I can't understand why the first value that I add to the last is not the true value
void process_data_directive(struct as_tree *node, char *line) {
    struct string_sep_result ssr = {0}; // Initialize ssr to avoid any uninitialized memory issues
    int count = get_dir_data_val(line, &ssr);
    if (count == -1) {
        snprintf(node->error, sizeof(node->error), "Error: Invalid number in .data directive.");
        return;
    }

    // Initialize the array to zero to ensure no leftover values
    memset(node->dir.operand_type.number, 0, sizeof(node->dir.operand_type.number));

    int num_index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ssr.strings_count; i++) {
        char *endptr;
        long value = strtol(ssr.strings[i], &endptr, 10);
        printf("num_index before adding: %d\n", num_index); // Debugging output
        printf("Converted value: %ld\n", value); // Debugging output
        if (*endptr != '\0') {
            snprintf(node->error, sizeof(node->error), "Error: Invalid number in .data directive.");
            for (int j = 0; j < ssr.strings_count; j++) {
                free(ssr.strings[j]);
            }
            return;
        }

        node->dir.operand_type.number[num_index] = (int)value;
        printf("Added number: %d at index %d\n", node->dir.operand_type.number[num_index], num_index); // Debugging output
        num_index++;
    }

    node->dir.operand_type.number_count = num_index;
    node->ast_type = ast_dir;
    node->dir.dir_type = ast_data;

    // Free the strings allocated in ssr
    for (int i = 0; i < ssr.strings_count; i++) {
        free(ssr.strings[i]);
    }

    // Print final stored numbers for debugging
    printf("Directive: data:");
    for (int i = 0; i < node->dir.operand_type.number_count; i++) {
        printf(" %d", node->dir.operand_type.number[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

Directive: data: 7 3 6 7 7 10 9
the right output would be 4 3 6 7 7 10 9 but instead seems like every time I check the first value is just the length of the elements
The tests are fine for all of the functions :
Extracted value: 4
Checking number: 4
Valid number
Extracted value: 3
Checking number: 3
Valid number
Extracted value: 6
Checking number: 6
Valid number
Extracted value: 7
Checking number: 7
Valid number
Extracted value: 7
Checking number: 7
Valid number
Extracted value: 10
Checking number: 10
Valid number
Extracted value: 9
Checking number: 9
Valid number
num_index before adding: 0
Converted value: 4
Added number: 4 at index 0
num_index before adding: 1
Converted value: 3
Added number: 3 at index 1
num_index before adding: 2
Converted value: 6
Added number: 6 at index 2
num_index before adding: 3
Converted value: 7
Added number: 7 at index 3
num_index before adding: 4
Converted value: 7
Added number: 7 at index 4
num_index before adding: 5
Converted value: 10
Added number: 10 at index 5
num_index before adding: 6
Converted value: 9
Added number: 9 at index 6

I can't figure my head around why that is happening

Please try to create a [mre] to show us, with the input hard-coded to replicate the problem in as small program as possible.
